# Django testrunner for both Celery and Selenium

Tags: django, selenium, celery, django-celery

[Django-celery](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/) expects me to set

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'
```

and [django-selenium](https://github.com/dragoon/django-selenium) expects me to set

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_selenium.selenium_runner.SeleniumTestRunner'.
```

How can I have both, i.e., both tests that run celery tasks locally and tests that use selenium to control a browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could probably define your own test runner that inherits from them both

(looking at the source for the two, the celery one actually just sets some settings)

so make some file e.g. `myapp.test_runner`, with

```
from djcelery.contrib.test_runner import CeleryTestSuiteRunner
django_selenium.selenium_runner import SeleniumTestRunner

class MyRunner(CeleryTestSuiteRunner, SeleniumTestRunner):
    pass
```

and then set

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'myproject.myapp.test_runner.MyRunner'
```